# Ascx control visible false issue

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ascx

I have a Tab control in one ASPX page which has 5 tabs. I am loading 5 ascx pages on this control. I have 4 ascx child controls inside the 2nd main ascx control. That is something like wizard on the 2nd main ascx page. When I load that 2nd TAB I will make it visible for 1st child ascx control. Based on the selection of any values on that control I am making visible true for the 2nd ascx child control and visible false for the 1st ascx child control. Thats not working. I am not able to see anything in the page. Its loading empty with out any controls.

What could be the issue?

Parent ascx - custom event from child ascx

```
         Private Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
            ReviewEnterReportDetailsId.Visible = True
            EnterReportDetailId.Visible = True
            EnterReportViewDetail1.Visible = True
        End Sub

         Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            ReviewEnterReportDetailsId.Visible = True
            EnterReportDetailId.Visible = False
            EnterReportViewDetail1.Visible = False
        End Sub

         Protected Sub ReviewEnterReportDetailsId_ERDScreenEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ReviewEnterReportDetailsId.ERDScreenEvent
            ReviewEnterReportDetailsId.Visible = False
            EnterReportDetailId.Visible = True
            EnterReportViewDetail1.Visible = False
        End Sub
```

Child ascx -

Just raising an event to change the next control

Comment: Added some updates to my answer - should get you going.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing actual code it's a little hard to say, however, when you use `Visible=False` nothing about that control will actually be rendered by .Net, hence seeing nothing in the source code view.

Ideally you should put these controls into a `<div>` and show/hide the `<div>` based on your conditions.

**UPDATE**

Also, looking at your (recently added) code, you start off in the `Init` by showing all 3 and then in the `load` you hide the last 2. Seems a little pointless as `load` is fired right after your `init`

Also - if you do not wrap your `load` and `init` code in `If (Not IsPostback)` then it will be fired everytime the page reloads. Wrap your code in `If (Not IsPostback)` and it will prevent the `load` from overriding what you set in `ReviewEnterReportDetailsId_ERDScreenEvent`